# C++ Queue I am getting thousands of errors even on line that doesnt exist on the code

Tags: c++

```
#define size 4
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class queue {
    int array[size];
    int rear;
    int front;

public:

    queue() {
        front = 0;
        rear = 0;
    }
    void enqueue(int val);
    void dequeue();
};
void queue :: enqueue(int val) {
    if (rear = size) {
        cout << "sorry our queue is full " << endl;
    }
    else {
        array[rear] = val;
        rear++;
    }
}
void queue :: dequeue() {
    if (front = rear) 
    {
        cout << "the stack is empty" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "our queued element is that" << array[front] << endl;
        front++;
    }}
int main() {

    queue bro;
    bro.enqueue(4);
    bro.enqueue(5);
    bro.enqueue(3);
    bro.enqueue(6);
    bro.dequeue();
    bro.dequeue();
    bro.dequeue();

}
```

I was writing the code and got a bunch of errors on this queue enqueue and dequeue array. The errors say corecrt_wio.h. Some of the errors say error on line that I didn't even write so it is really confusing.

Comment: `using namespace std;` may be part of your problem. The standard library has a `size` and `queue`. Read about the problems it can cause here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: `if (front = rear)` is a most likely a bug. `=` is an assignment. Use `==` for comparison.

Comment: `if (rear = size)` and `if (front = rear)` both look wrong. Renaming `size` to something like `sz` fixes the issue. https://godbolt.org/z/x1fKTvjf7 Gotta be careful with defines, the potential for a conflict is huge, especially with `using namesapce std`.

Answer (score 5):

Writing

```
#define size 4
```

at the top of your file is insane. Never do this. There are good reasons why macro constants are discouraged in favour of something like

```
constexpr size_t size = 4;
```

and one of then is that you've replaced every token "size" in the standard iostream library header - and every header included by that - with the integer literal `4`.

Every local variable that was called "size" is now just the character `4`. Any method called size is now called `4`. These text substitutions happen everywhere, even when they make no sense.

When macros *are* used, they're named something like `MY_UNIQUE_PREFIX_MACRO` specifically to avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the errors compiling your code, and the problem seems to be at line 1: `#define size 4`, `size` seems to be a macro used in other source files in g++. Renaming this to `sz` solves the problem. As well, the `if` statements use only 1 `=`, for these `if` statements, use `==` instead.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a macro (and I'm sure the standard library is better written than to use a macro with a name like that). It just has to be a token.